# React Native Tools in VS Code. Nothing in Debug Console

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, expo, native

I have installed VS Code on a fresh load on Ubuntu. Im trying to start a new react native project with Expo and I want to be able to debug in VS Code using the React Native Tools extension. I had it set up on my laptop with ubuntu and it worked ok. Now running it on my PC when I click on Start Debug it runs for about 2 seconds and stops. Absolutely nothing shows up in the Debug console. Running Node 14.4.0. Deleted everything and ran `expo init` a couple times: no change.  Anyone encounter anything like this before?

Comment: I think this might happen due to lack of memory issue. Since you are using expo in your project, this increases memory consumption for bundling purposes. I did clean installation of the Ubuntu and expo clients many times (16GB RAM) and haven't experienced any issues whatsoever.

Comment: My PC has a core i7 with 16gb ram. Maybe a driver issue though?

Comment: Your configuration looks identical to mine. It could be an driver issue, but I doubt it.